# Анимация для прокрутки блоков вперед и назад

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Имеется такая вот ячейка в таблице, в которой находятся блоки. Все они не вмещаются по ширине ячейки и необходимо добавить функционал прокрутки вперед и назад.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никогда до сегодняшнего дня такого не делал и способов решения такой задачи не знаю. Первое, что пришло в голову:

1. Задать ширину блока, в котром находятся все элементы, как `ширинаЭлемента * количествоЭлементов + отступы`.
2. Задать блоку overflow: hidden;
3. При нажатии на стрелку вперед блоку, содержащему элементы, делать что-то вроде: `margin-left: ширинаЭлемента`. Стрелка назад - тоже самое, но `margin-right`;

Может быть существуют более очевидные способы решения такой задачи? Спасибо!

Comment: Может просто внутри ячейки прикрутить слайдер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы все верно думаете. Только не margin используйте, а `.scrollLeft` и `.scrollRight` по клику с шагом по ширине внутреннего блока.

```js
var holder = $(".inner-cont");
var scrollstep = 68;

$(".left").bind("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  holder.animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=" + scrollstep + "px"
  });
});
$(".right").bind("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  holder.animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=" + scrollstep + "px"
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 35px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.inner-cont {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background: #eee;
}

.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="left">←</div>
  <div class="inner-cont">
    <div class="inner" style="background:red"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:green"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:blue"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:orange"></div>
    <div class="inner" style="background:tomato"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">→</div>
</div>
```